# GetSystemService(ConnectivityService) returns null when trying to check internet connection Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, internet-connection

I am making an Android application using Xamarin.Android and using the following tutorial provided by Xamarin to check if there is internet connection available: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/networkinfo/detect_network_connection/

In the first part of the tutorial I need to create a Connectivity manager object and use GetSystemService to initialize it.

Here is the line of code:

```
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
```

When I run the application an exception get thrown of type System.NullReferenceException. And the message states: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: do you have the required permissions set in your manifest?  What version of Android are you using?

Comment: Yes, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE must be checked. And I did so according to the tutorial. Targeting a minimum of Android 5.1 or API level 22 (Lollipop)